# Create a lateral box with chapter/section name with Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I want to create a table of content like box on the left side of every slide with the name of every chapter/section and with the current chapter/section name highlighted while the other are slightly faded. Like in the following picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sidebar` outer theme will add such a sidebar navigation to your presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}

\begin{document}

\section{title 1}    
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{title 2}    
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are several ready-to-use themes with this kind of navigation bar, see e.g. https://github.com/UweZiegenhagen/LaTeX-Beamer-Theme-Overview/blob/main/OVERVIEW.md for an overview

Comment: Is it possible to customize this sidebar? Like change, it's thickness?

Comment: @GabrielMarino Sure: `\useoutertheme[width=5cm,height=1cm]{sidebar}`